# How to achieve mathematical expression in postgres SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, relational-database, rdbms

I have a kind of requirement to find out **"Main Balance"** from a  PostgreSQL database table.

Here, The Logic is pretty much easy likewise,

> Main Balance = Credit + Refund - Debit

I have a database table likewise,

**Table Name :-** `Account`

**Columns :-** `id, source_account_number, destination_account_number, transaction_type, amount, creation_date_time`

Here, `transaction_type` could have following set of possible values, ***CREDIT, REFUND, DEBIT***.

Now, I would like to know for example what's my A/c balance then logic should be likewise,

> Main Balance = sum of **all** `CREDIT` entries + sum of **all** `REFUND` entries -
>   sum of **all** `DEBIT` entries.

So Basically, I am trying to achieve this through a single query.

For example(I know it's wrong but still let me paint),

```
select sum(amount) from Account where destination_account_number = 'XYZ' and transaction_type in ('CREDIT', 'REFUND');
```

But It'll return only *deposited* amount itself, what about **DEBIT**.

*Obviously we can recover those as well but it's promoting for multiple query.*

Can Anyone help me to do this through easiest, optimised way to achieve this functionality ?

*Any help will really appreciable to all those who will show their interest !!*

**UPDATE -** 
Here, `transaction_type` could have following set of possible values, ***CREDIT, REFUND, DEBIT, OTHERS, PENDING, EXPIRED***.
Now, Please consider Main Balance logic :- CREDIT + REFUND - DEBIT where PENDING, EXPIRED Money will be **skipped** in a main-balance calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with conditional aggregation.

```
select sum(case when transaction_type in ('CREDIT', 'REFUND') then amount else -amount end) 
from Account 
where destination_account_number = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: could you please scratch about DEBIT transaction. I mean how could I handle it along with your answer ?

Comment: could you please review my UPDATE section at the last bottom of the page & let me know how could handle those statuses.

Comment: Alright, I am good with the following query,
select sum(case when transaction_type in ('CREDIT', 'REFUND') then amount when transaction_type in ('DEBIT') then - amount end) 
from Account 
where destination_account_number = 'XYZ'